# Connection reset when unable to write into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this method here - whenever I comment out the MySQL section, from `String query` to `pst.close()` - the code works fine. However, if I don't, then it gives me the error of `Connection Reset`. I am using a socket between a client and a server for your information. How would I fix this? Or it it a problem that does not deal with MySQL?

```
public static String doAddUser(String username, String password, String email, String fullname) throws SQLException {
    String returnStatement = "";
    Connection connection = establishConnection();

    if(email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
        returnStatement = "CreateFailure: Some fields are left blank. Please note that all fields are required. Please try again";
    }

    else {

        String query = "insert into test(`username`, `password`, `email`, `fullname`) values (?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, username);
        pst.setString(2, password);
        pst.setString(3, email);
        pst.setString(4, fullname);
        pst.executeUpdate();
        pst.close();
        returnStatement = "CreateSuccess: You are now registered!";
    }
    return returnStatement;
}
```

Comment: What does `establishConnection` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably have a `connection.close()` before the return.

Or, if you are in a relatively new version of JRE, you could possibly achieve the same with `try-with-resource`.

```
public static String doAddUser(String username, String password, String email, String fullname) throws SQLException {

    String returnStatement = "";

    try (Connection connection = establishConnection()) {

        if(email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            returnStatement = "CreateFailure: Some fields are left blank. Please note that all fields are required. Please try again";
        }
        else {
            String query = "insert into test(`username`, `password`, `email`, `fullname`) values (?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, username);
            pst.setString(2, password);
            pst.setString(3, email);
            pst.setString(4, fullname);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            pst.close();
            returnStatement = "CreateSuccess: You are now registered!";
        }
    }

    return returnStatement;
}
```

This will ensure that your connection closes when the `try` block finishes. However, that would require that the `Connection` class implements the `AutoCloseable` interface.

Comment: For some reasons, I tried both closing the connection and try statement but both could not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the connection is getting established and not getting closed, might be the issue.

Comment: For some reasons, I tried both closing the connection and try statement but both could not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me, as suggested by @Binaek Sarkar (I modified it a little bit):

```
public static String doAddUser(String username, String password, String email, String fullname) throws SQLException {
    String returnStatement = "";
    try {
        if(email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            returnStatement = "CreateFailure: Some fields are left blank. Please note that all fields are required. Please try again";
            }
        else {
            Connection connection = null;
            connection = MySQLConnection.dbConnector();
            String query = "INSERT INTO `test`(`username`, `password`, `email`, `fullname`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, username);
            pst.setString(2, password);
            pst.setString(3, email);
            pst.setString(4, fullname);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            pst.close();

            returnStatement = "CreateSuccess: You are now registered! You will redirected to the login page now. ";
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {returnStatement = "Invalid. Please try again!";}

    return returnStatement;
}
```